# How to find multiple solutions for 3 variable, 2 degree Diophantine equation?

Tags: diophantine-equations

I have the equation $x^2+xy+y^2=z^2$ to solve it in natural numbers.

The discriminant of it $D=4z^2-3y^2$ and must be perfect square.

I wrote Python program to get solutions for $1<x<100$ by enumeration.

```
def Solution():
    A=[]
    nMaximum=10**2
    for x in range(1,nMaximum):
        dTemp1a=3*x**2
        for z in range(x+1, nMaximum):
            dDiscriminant=4*z**2-dTemp1a
            dTemp5=int(dDiscriminant**0.5)
            if dTemp5**2!=dDiscriminant:
                continue
            dTemp6=(-1*x+dTemp5)/2
            y=int(dTemp6)
            if not CheckIfExists(A, z):
                A.append([x,y,z])
    return A

def CheckIfExists(arr, z):
    bResult=False
    for s in arr:
        if s[2]==z:
            bResult=True
            break
    return bResult

a = Solution()
print(len(a))
print(a)

# [3, 5, 7], [5, 16, 19], [6, 10, 14], [7, 8, 13] ...
```

[Three variable, second degree diophantine equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1351994/three-variable-second-degree-diophantine-equation) doesn't explain how to get other solutions when we know the first solution $(3,5,7)$

Could you give me a hint ?

UPDATE asked by Shean: I need to get all solutions based on $(3,5,7)$. See my question as the example of what I am looking for:

> [First 30 solutions of Pell's equation.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2392702/356852)

or see these formulas for all solutions of Pell's equation

> http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PellEquation.html

Comment: The first answer by Daniel Shepler to the article you link to explains how to get more solutions from any starting solution, giving explicit formulas for the "next" solution from a given solution. This is not guaranteed to produce all solutions from a single one; there are some such equations which end up having several different start solutions from which to generate the rest.

Comment: https://www.math.utoronto.ca/barbeau/vig23.pdf

Comment: @Sil That link is to a parametric solution. However OP asks about the method to generate new solutions from old.

Comment: @Shean They have partial number of solutions like _coffeemath_ said. https://www.math.utoronto.ca/barbeau/vig23.pdf has $(x,y,z)=(2k+1,k^2-1,k^2+k+1)$ where $k>1$.

Comment: @coffeemath Just multiply a solution by an integer to produce infinitely many other solutions....

Comment: @yW0K5o haven't verified everything, but they claim that every 120 triangle arises that way.

Comment: @Shean I verified "Geometry" section of document with 2 conditions for $120^o$ triangles (additional: $2*t+1, t*(3*t+2), 3*t*(t+1)+1$). I found that it was missing 50% solutions to compare with enumeration.

Comment: @Shean the equation here is homogeneous, so "multiply one solution by an integer" produces nothing but trivial variations of a given solution.

Comment: @yW0K5o enumeration also produces answers which have $gcd(x,y,z)\neq 1$. These are called non-primitive solutions. The formulas above are for producing primitive solutions. See my answer.

Comment: "From here, all primitive solutions can be obtained by dividing a, b, and c by their greatest common divisor. " From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_triangle#Integer_triangles_with_a_120.C2.B0_angle

Answer (score 1):

Can't fit this into a comment so I'll make it an answer.

Firstly, your question isn't clear.

> [Three variable, second degree diophantine equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1351994/three-variable-second-degree-diophantine-equation) doesn't explain how to get other solutions when we know the first solution $(3,5,7)$

If you are expecting to generate ALL triples from $(3,5,7)$ then I don't think this is possible (actually it may be possible, see Will's comment). If you simply want more solutions then take the triple $(3k,5k,7k)$ for any positive integer $k$.

Now if you're wondering why the solutions to formulas such as
\begin{equation}
x=m^2-n^2\\
y=2mn+n^2\\\tag{1}
z=m^2+mn+n^2
\end{equation}
where $n<m$ and $\gcd(m,n)=1$ produce less results to: simply plugging in values  for $x$ and $y$ and checking if $x^2+xy+y^2$ is a square, is because $(1)$ generates *primitive* solutions, that is $\gcd(x,y,z)=1$.

(Note: $(1)$ sometimes produces non-primitive solutions, to remedy this, simply divide $x,y,z$ by $\gcd(x,y,z)$)

Some example code using the system $(1)$ producing only primitive triples:

```
import math

limit = 10
triples = []

for n in range(1, limit):
    for m in range(n + 1, limit):
        if math.gcd(m, n) == 1:
            x = m**2 - n**2
            y = 2 * m * n + n**2
            z = m**2 + m * n + n**2
            if y<x:
                x_temp = x
                x=y
                y=x_temp
            d=math.gcd(x,math.gcd(y,z)) #removing non-primitives
            triples.append((int(x/d), int(y/d), int(z/d)))

#remove duplicates
triples= list(dict.fromkeys(triples))

# Sort the triples based on x and then y
sorted_triples = sorted(triples, key=lambda triple: (triple[0], triple[1]))

for triple in sorted_triples:
    print("x =", triple[0])
    print("y =", triple[1])
    print("z =", triple[2])
    print()
```

Some example code plugging values for $x$ and $y$ and simply verifying the equation (This is what your code above was doing):

```
limit = 100
x=1
y=1
while x<limit:
    y=x
    while y<limit:
        z=(x**2+x*y+y**2)**0.5
        if z==int(z):
            print("x="+str(x)+"\ny="+str(y)+"\nz="+str(int(z))+"\n")
        y+=1
    x+=1
```

You can verify for yourself that any solution from the second code is a non-primitive. Or, you can run a variant of the first code which multiplies each primitive by $k=2,3,4,5$ and notice that the outputs are the same. Simply replace:

```
d=math.gcd(x,math.gcd(y,z)) #removing non-primitives
triples.append((int(x/d), int(y/d), int(z/d)))
```

with

```
for k in range(2,5):
    triples.append((x*k,y*k,z*k))
```

Comment: If you want to pursue:  there should be a method   similar to    https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_of_primitive_Pythagorean_triples  by replacing Barning's matrix $B$   with $$
B = 
 \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
4 & 3 & 4 \\ 
3 & 4 & 4 \\ 
6 & 6 & 7 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

Comment: Very interesting! I'll check out the proof in the morning